# Change part of url link when user press text with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, text, replace, onclick

Is there any easy way to do this (with pure javascript)?

If i have

```
<span>text1.de</span>
<span>text2.com</span>
<span>text3.pl</span>
.
.
.

<a href="https://xxxxx.com/example/">https://xxxxx.com/example/</a>
<a href="https://xxxxx.com/example2/">https://xxxxx.com/example2/</a>
<a href="https://xxxxx.com/example3/">https://xxxxx.com/example3/</a>
<a href="https://xxxxx.com/example4/">https://xxxxx.com/example4/</a>
.
.
.
```

I want that when an user press text1.de or text2.com... all xxxxx.com links are replaced by that text.
For example if the user presses text1.de all links are

```
<a href="https://text1.de/example/">https://text1.de/example/</a>
<a href="https://text1.de/example2/">https://text1.de/example2/</a>
<a href="https://text1.de/example3/">https://text1.de/example3/</a>
<a href="https://text1.de/example4/">https://text1.de/example4/</a>
.
.
.
```

if presses text3.com all link are

```
<a href="https://text3.com/example/">https://text3.com/example/</a>
<a href="https://text3.com/example2/">https://text3.com/example2/</a>
<a href="https://text3.com/example3/">https://text3.com/example3/</a>
<a href="https://text3.com/example4/">https://text3.com/example4/</a>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of all the conditions in your case, but at least this does the job. It replaces the parts of the string you've declared in dataset ('data-to-be-replaced') and replaces them with string you've declared in the button ('data-replacer'):

```js
const replacers = document.querySelectorAll('.replacer');
const replaceUs = document.querySelectorAll('.replaceMe');


const replaceLinks = (evt) => {
  const button = evt.currentTarget;
  const { replacer } = button.dataset;
  
  replaceUs.forEach((elem) => {
    const wholeString = elem.getAttribute('href');
    const toBeReplaced = elem.dataset.toBeReplaced;
    const stringWithReplacement = wholeString.replace(toBeReplaced, replacer);
    
    elem.dataset.toBeReplaced = replacer;
    elem.setAttribute('href', stringWithReplacement);
    elem.textContent = stringWithReplacement;
  });
}

replacers.forEach((replacer) => replacer.addEventListener('click', replaceLinks));
```

```html
<button class='replacer' data-replacer='test'>Replace with "test"</button>
<button class='replacer' data-replacer='test2'>Replace with "test2"</button>

<ul>
<li><a class='replaceMe' href="https://xxxxx.com/example/" data-to-be-replaced='xxxxx' >https://xxxxx.com/example/</a></li>
<li><a class='replaceMe' href="https://xxxxx.com/example2/" data-to-be-replaced='xxxxx'>https://xxxxx.com/example2/</a></li>
<li><a class='replaceMe' href="https://xxxxx.com/example3/" data-to-be-replaced='xxxxx'>https://xxxxx.com/example3/</a></li>
<li><a class='replaceMe' href="https://xxxxx.com/example4/" data-to-be-replaced='xxxxx'>https://xxxxx.com/example4/</a></li>
</ul>
```